# Converter Bitmap/Drawable em Drawable (int)

Tags: android, conversão-de-tipo, drawable, bitmap

Preciso converter um Bitmap ou até mesmo um Drawable em um Drawable (int), pois estou utilizando um Bootstrap para android que necessita de um objeto desse tipo, mas como estou baixando a imagem de uma url e não pegando ela internamente, não estou conseguindo.

Segue o trecho:

```
Bitmap bitIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitIcon);
imgPerfil.setImage();
```

Na terceira linha ele pede um inteiro, mas eu só tenho o Objeto Drawable e não o seu id. Queria saber como buscar este inteiro.

Comment: segue o link da biblioteca bootstrap-android que estou utilizando https://github.com/Bearded-Hen/Android-Bootstrap/wiki/Bootstrap-Thumbnail

Answer (score 1):

Para converter um `Bitmap` em `Drawable` faça o seguinte:

```java
Drawable seuDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),seuBitmap);
```

Porém, Conforme você pediu, necessitas buscar o `Drawable` pelo id então utilize:

```
Bitmap seuBitmap = (Bitmap) findViewById(R.id.seuIdDoDrawable);
Drawable seuDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),seuBitmap);
```

Comment: Mas eu preciso do 'id' do Drawable, como se fosse buscado internamente

Comment: veja minha edição na resposta @lucasrafagnin

Comment: Estou baixando o Bitmap de um link externo, e convertendo ele para Drawable. Eu não tenho ele internamente

Comment: Então você já tem um `Drawable`, qual seria seu problema??

Comment: Realmente minha pergunta ficou confusa, eu tenho o objeto Drawable. Porém no metodo setImage() ele solicita um int, e eu não estou conseguindo fazer esta conversão.

Comment: O int que você está falando é o int retornado por `R.drawable.seuDrawable` porém você não tem ele na View ainda, que tal adicionar ele a view? Posteriormente você pode resgatar o ID.

Comment: Você deve salvar o Drawable na pasta `/res/drawable` para que ele se torne um Resource e então você terá um ID do tipo `R.drawable.seuDrawable`.

Comment: Ok, e como eu faria esta gravação?

Comment: O problema é que é impossível gravar na pasta `res/drawable` em tempo de execução, estou pensando em outra forma de você resgatar o ID...

Comment: Tente utilizar `drawable.createFromStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream(), testDrawable)` e depois verificar se `R.drawable.testDrawable` existe.

Comment: não funcionou, mas resolvi fazer de outra forma, e não utilizar o bootstrap nesse caso. Obrigado pela ajuda.